# AJAX call never reaching error statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

In the AJAX call below, I am attempting to debug the JavaScript call to understand why I cannot get to the error block when checking for failures. Whenever I debug in Chrome Developer tools, it jumps to the last line of the function and not the error block. Is there a easier way to test why this isn't being hit?

```
$("#input-userName").blur(function () {
var userNameTxt = $("#input-userName").val();

if (userNameTxt != prevUserName) {
    if (userNameTxt.length >= 6 && userNameTxt.length <= 20) {
        $("#divVerifyUserName").show();
        $("#input-userName").prop("disabled", true);

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: BASE_URL + "MyCall",
            async: true,
            data: { 'userName': userNameTxt },
            success: function (resultset) {
                prevUserName = userNameTxt
                $("#userNameValidationMessage").removeClass("error");

                if (resultset != null) {

                    $("#divVerifyUserName").hide();
                    $("#input-userName").prop("disabled", false);


                    if (resultset.status) {
                        $("#userNameValidationMessage").addClass("message");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#userNameValidationMessage").removeClass("message");
                        $("#userNameValidationMessage").addClass("error");
                    }

                    $("#userNameValidationMessage").text(resultset.msg);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, error) {
                $("#userNameValidationMessage").text("Error while processing the request. Please try again.");
            }
        });

    }
}
});
```

Comment: Is an error actually happening for it to ever execute? 404 or otherwise?

Comment: Yes, I am hard coding a bad URL and my server-side code is throwing an exception as it should.

Comment: in chrome developer tools select `network` then call the ajax and in the `xhr` tab check for the request and check the status and details about the request.